# Accessing a Button in Another XAML File (UWP)

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, uwp-xaml

I have two XAML files (MainPage and SettingsPage), and in MainPage I have a button, and I like (I do not know if it is possible) to access this button in the SettingsPage. I have tried several forms, for example something like this: MainPage.MyButton and nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with MVVM pattern you can call methods from another ViewModel.
You can also take help from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126317/accessing-a-button-created-in-a-sub-xaml-page-from-its-parent-shell-xaml)

Comment: I was watching this page and did not notice anything. I do not know how to do it, I just want to access a button that is in another XAML file

Comment: I do not know what this is